# installing Google Cloud on ChromeOS via the command line Terminal results in "permission denied" errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I'm attempting to install Google Cloud on ChromeOS via the command line Terminal. I get "permission denied" errors despite having chmod rwx permissions on all the files and folders in my path back to /root. The owner is Chronos and the user is also Chronos. No Google search suggestions have turned up any solutions.

```
chronos@localhost /media/fuse/drivefs-ba088db4f3fc3d98ca0829baa8b3fbc6/root/Dev $ curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   443  100   443    0     0   2248      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2237
Downloading Google Cloud SDK install script: https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash
######################################################################## 100.0%
Running install script from: /tmp/tmp.6MQEnIbZB3/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash
bash: line 14: /tmp/tmp.6MQEnIbZB3/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash: Permission denied
```

Comment: It would seem that since you are running the command `curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash` from `.../root/Dev`could be the issue.  Because of the temp folders permissions where the files are held.
`ls -ld /tmp/tmp.6MQEnIbZB3/` should be showing missing permissions.
You could check these tmp folders permissions or try to install from a different location.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't find any tmp folders anywhere to list.

Comment: have you tried running it step by step in home/user?
1. `cd ~ `
2. `curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-334.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`
3. `tar -xf google-cloud-sdk-334.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`
4.  `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the result is the same: 
chronos@localhost /media/fuse/drivefs-ba088db4f3fc3d98ca0829baa8b3fbc6/root $ cd ~
chronos@localhost ~ $ curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-334.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

Comment: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 80.4M  100 80.4M    0     0  18.6M      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 18.6M
chronos@localhost ~ $ tar -xf google-cloud-sdk-334.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
chronos@localhost ~ $ ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
bash: ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh: Permission denied
chronos@localhost ~ $

Comment: QQ, do you have developer mode enabled?----I think this is why you are having permission problems, these 
The common steps to turn on Developer Mode on Chromebook are:
Turn off your ChromeBook.
Holding Esc + Refresh (F3) buttons while pressing Power button. Then release Power Button.
Your screen will display Recovery screen. Here, press Ctrl+D to turn on Developer mode. Then wait for couple of minutes.